# Month Name and Last date of each month for previous 3 months in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-arithmetic

I'm analyzing customer transactions for the previous 3 months, excluding the current month, I would like to get the month names of the previous 3 months and the last date of each of the 3 months.

```
WITH R(N) AS (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT N+1 FROM R WHERE N < 3
)
SELECT 
    LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,-N,GETDATE())),3) AS [month], 
    DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(MONTH,-N,GETDATE())) AS [year]
FROM R;
```

---output

```
month   year
Aug     2019
Jul     2019
Jun     2019
```

---expected

```
month EOM_Date    year
Aug   2019-08-31  2019
Jul   2019-07-31  2019
Jun   2019-06-30  2019
```

Comment: For sql server (which you seem to be using) you can use [EOMONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Several product specific functions are used.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SQL Server `EOMONTH()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to compute the last day of a month.

Consider:

```
WITH R(N) AS (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT N+1 FROM R WHERE N < 3
)
SELECT 
    LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,-N,GETDATE())),3) AS [month], 
    EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -N) AS [EOM_DATE],
    DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(MONTH,-N,GETDATE())) AS [year]
FROM R;
```